# Pagination in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pagination

Good afternoon, directly I apologize for spelling and not literacy, I badly know English.
Question in the following - I can't make browsing of pages in jqgrid, generally shall work so:

```
onPaging : function(pgButton)
{
     var nextPg = $("#users").getGridParam("page");
     $("#editGrid").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:nextPg}]);
}
```

that seems to me that or locks a code or that that isn't enough. Prompt in what a problem?

code:

```
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        height: '100%',
        gridview: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        rowNum: 100,         
        rowList: [100, 500, 1000],
        autoencode: true,
        loadonce:true, 
        pager: '#pager', 
        search:true,
        multiselect: true,
        autowidth: true, 
        onPaging : function(pgButton){

         var nextPg = $("#users").getGridParam("page");
         $("#editGrid").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:nextPg}]);
        },
```

I wrote the pagination, but a code big and it would be desirable to replace it with more convenient and small code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `loadonce:true` option then the server should return **all data** instead of returning the data for one page only. The usage of `loadonce:true` option is very practical if you need display not so many rows (for example less as 1000 rows). So you should either remove `loadonce:true` option of modify your server code to return **all pages** at once.

If you really have some complex scenario and you need use `loadonce:true`, but to implement server side paging then you should set `datatype` to `"local"` inside of `onPaging`. You should never call `reloadGrid` directly inside of `onPaging`. jqGrid do this itself.

Comment: Yes I tried to clean "loadonce:true", but then a pagination <<page:1 of 2>> become inactive, or they as that can be activated without "loadonce:true"?

And in onPaging as I understood it is necessary to write so:

var nextPg = $ ("#users") .getGridParam ("page");
$ ("#users") .setGridParam ({ rowNum: nextPg });

Comment: @Casper: Sorry, but I can't follow you. **Do you have the demo which reproduces the problem?** How many rows returns the server at the first loading of data? Is it all rows which you have? You use `rowNum: 100`, but it's clear that one can't display 100 rows on the screen at once. So the user have to use both scrolling to see the first 100 rows and paging to see the next 100 rows. I find it not consequent. You should **don't change `rowNum`** inside of `onPaging`. I wrote that you could set `datatype` to `"json"` because it will be changed to `"local"` because of using `loadonce:true`.

Comment: I understood, at me anyway returns json all data, and not just the first 100, even without "loadonce:true" in it is visible also a problem. The working code is, but it corporate and there you need to create the account for an entrance. Thanks for the help, I will think as it to correct.

Answer (score 0):

By the way to whom it is interesting (I don't know on how many it optimum), I made it thus:
in js

```
onPaging : function(pgButton){
            var gridParamRowNum = $('#users').getGridParam('rowNum');
            var gridParamRowAll = $('#users').getGridParam('records');
            var gridParamPage = $('#users').getGridParam('page');
            if(pgButton === 'next_pager') 
            {
                gridParamPage = gridParamPage + 1;
            }else
            {
                gridParamPage = gridParamPage - 1;
                gridParamRowAll = gridParamRowAll + 100;
            }
                AdminUsers.ajaxParams.gridParamPage = gridParamRowNum * gridParamPage - 100;
                AdminUsers.ajaxParams.gridParamRowNum = gridParamRowAll;
        },
```

where AdminUsers.ajaxParams.gridParamPage and AdminUsers.ajaxParams.gridParamRowNum is POST requests for the server,

and for php:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['gridParamPage']) && isset($_REQUEST['gridParamRowNum'])) {
        $limit = $_REQUEST['gridParamRowNum'];
        $offset = $_REQUEST['gridParamPage'];
        $usersFactory->setLimit((int)$limit)->setOffset((int)$offset);
    }
```

and by means of the setLimit and setOffset functions the inquiry gets out and sent to the client